# How can I hide every single possible tooltip or popup in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've tried just about every setting I could find in order to turn off these tool tips but to my dismay, they keep popping up almost every time I write a function.

[image: Parameter hints are disabled, but still here it is]

I've seen on some other threads that this may be specific to the language highlighting I'm using for JS, and that may be the source of the issue. If so, is there another one I can use that won't pollute my screen and hide my code from me?

I've been searching for answers to this question on and off for weeks, and am quickly approaching my breaking point. There is absolutely no circumstance that would cause me to want 6-8 lines of my code obstructed from me, and I just want this and all other tooltips to go away. Thanks in advance.

Aaaaaaaand my config settings for completeness:

```
{
    "editor.referenceInfos"         : false,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled" : false,
    "editor.parameterHints"         : false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions"       : false,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently `"editor.quickSuggestions"` is now deprecated, and `"editor.referenceInfos"` has changed to `"editor.codeLens"`